# SQLite delete syntax error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

This line, `mDatabase.execSQL(sql);`, gives me the following error:

```
{ sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "*": syntax error }
  for Delete * from table_name Query
```

My SQL query is : `DELETE * FROM table_name`

How can I solve this?

Comment: can u put your log cat here..

Comment: i am unable to attach the log cat now, but I need to tell you one thing, That statement mDatabase.execSQL(sql);  is working fine for the query like: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE key=2 . But for this DELETE * FROM table_name only this is not working. i am using  sql cipher library (jar) for the Database operations.  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`DELETE * FROM table_name` is a wrong sql command. Use `DELETE from table_name`

Comment: For a simple reason- you can only delete the row, not a certain set of columns which * denotes.

Comment: I need to delete complete table, As per your query we can delete only one row that to we need to use WHERE clause with some primary key value.

Comment: use this query without where and you delete all rows from table

Comment: ok thanks, let me try this and i need to change one thing that my query is correct only right, because i need to support both queries (if both are correct) [link] (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) to delete all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error means that basically your statement is spelled wrong and it can not be parsed. In this case error message states where exactly this error occurred - on "*" character. In such case you should go to database documentation and check proper syntax of the command you are trying to use. In case of SQLite it's [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html/). You can find documentation about DELETE statement there, [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) is the link. It shows you the syntax in graphical way (called [syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) or railroad diagrams) which should be quite easy to follow. 
In this case, as mentioned earlier, you just can't specify "*" between DELETE and FROM. This is because you are always deleting whole rows and you can't delete individual selected columns.

Comment: thanks, i understand something but right now i am using sql cipher library (jar) for the database operations. Is there any way to find wheather this sqlcipher.jar will support this type of query.?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, sqlchipher should not influence sql queries in any way and it should support the same queries (and the same syntax) as normal SQLite.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your reply, then why i am getting this error particularity for this query only. It is working fine for the DELETE FROM table_name WHERE key=3, it is giving the error for DELETE * FROM only. I am using same mDatabase.exceSQL(sql) same statement to execute all the Queries. Any other way to solve this.

Comment: You should use `DELETE FROM table_name`, you can't use '*' inside the query. You are just using wrong syntax. If you want to delete all the rows you use `DELETE FROM table_name` without any WHERE clause and that's all.

Comment: thanks. I will do this implementation and get back to you if it works. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the entire table can you use DROP TABLE IF EXISTS then recreate the table

Comment: Thanks. As per the Krzysztof Adamski words i solved this. Thank you very much for your valuable Time.